# How many first-author papers should I publish during postdoc to get a tenure-track faculty position?

Tags: publications, tenure-track

I'm currently a 2nd year postdoc in mechanical engineering field working on bio-related applications. I have ~9 first-author papers during my Ph. D., but have not been able to publish a first-author paper during postdoc. 
For anyone in a similar situation (postdoc in mech. working on bio stuff), what is the reasonable number of 1st author papers to apply for TT? If I have several non first-author papers, would that still "count" as my research output when getting reviewed by the search committee?

Comment: The answer depends massively on the subject and profile of place you are applying to. Also, the number of papers is not the best metrics - the quality matters more.

Comment: I don't understand how an answer will help you. You have what you have. But an application for an academic job isn't an accounting problem, simply counting up papers. More is better, of course. But hopefully you have other qualities that make you desirable as a faculty member. Work hard, but don't be discouraged. Don't let fear of failure hold you back.

Answer (score 1):

I think quality of the work is more important than number or papers.  Even more important than first-author status.

Of course non-first-author papers count; for exapmle, get the actual first author to write one of your recommendation letters, to describe your contribution to the research.